# Android Safe vs Unsafe Usage of Inner Classes

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks

I'm new to Android development and I've been having a lot of trouble finding ways to make sure my app doesn't leak memory. I've read online that using inner classes can cause memory leaks, especially when they may outlive their Activity. Here are some of the inner classes I use. Which of these, if any, could cause a memory leak?

```
public class TitleScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen);
    final MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mHandler.mActivity.get(), IntroActivity.class);
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(intent);
            mHandler.mActivity.get().finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
}

private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    public final WeakReference<TitleScreenActivity> mActivity;

    public MyHandler(TitleScreenActivity activity) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }
}
}
```

I based this code off of what I found in [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html#more). However, I don't think it would be possible for me to make my Runnable static, like they did in the article. Can this code cause a memory leak, even though I finish the Activity in the runnable?

Another example:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.no_tiles);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.store, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // start new Activity
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Do nothing, just close dialog
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

I have trouble believing that this could cause a leak because it doesn't contain an explicit reference to an Activity, View, etc and it (to the best of my knowledge) the dialog gets destroyed when the user clicks a button, so the listeners would be destroyed as well. However, I wanted to make sure.

Last example:

```
        TranslateAnimation translate;
        translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 100);
        translate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // modify a few variables
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        translate.setDuration(200);
        findViewById(R.id.game_board).startAnimation(translate);
```

I'm not sure if this could cause because theoretically the animation could outlive the Activity it's in.

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: wow!! honestly sir, if you are unsure override finish() and explicitly nullify all "i am not sure this will leak my activity" its fine, my only question is why do you pass your activity to your inner class?

Comment: Well I don't want to call finish() on most of my Activities because then the user couldn't press the back button to return to the previous Activity. I pass the Activity to the inner class because that's what was done in the article I linked to. I'm not sure that I really need to do so, but if nothing else it's a convenient place to store a reference to the Activity so that I can finish it in the Runnable.

Comment: have you tried using MAT tool? it looks ok to me Sir, but honestly if you want to take control of your app's behavior you need to take control. hope it helps